# Fail to send an email with mail() php function

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
   SendEmail("makovetskiyd@yahoo.co.uk","Dima", "trololo");
   function SendEmail($to,$user_name, $user_password)
   {

     $subject="Political forum: registration";
     $body = 'Your user name is: ".$user_name  <br/>'.$user_name.' Your password is: '.$user_password.'<br/><br/> Click the link below for validation: <a href="#">Validation_Link</a>';

     $headers="FROM: $to\r\n";
     $headers.=" Content=type: text/html\r\n";


   if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
       echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
      } else {
       echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
      }
   }

?>
```

The above fails!!!

I had a little read and I found that you need to change this inyour php.ini:

> > ; For Win32 only. ; 
> >         http://php.net/smtp SMTP = localhost ;
> >     http://php.net/smtp-port smtp_port = 25
> >
> > ; For Win32 only.  ; http://php.net/sendmail-from sendmail_from =
> >     yourguru27@gmail.com

I did, but it still fails

Message:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\email.php on line 16
```

Message delivery failed...

Comment: "Fails" means what? Any error messages?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If it is a silent error, try to var_dump error_get_last() after executing mail()

Comment: sorry forgot to add...added above

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server set up on your machine?

Comment: well, I am not sure what it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a small thing.. the text you sent doesn't look fine.. but I guess that you will fix that if you get it to work..

about why it doesn't work: you seem to try to send to an yahoo address.. a lot of servers refuse mails that come from the same address (especially that you are sending from your own server, and not yahoo)

so instead of using the user's email address as sender pick another one
so you need to change this line:

```
$headers="FROM: $to\r\n";
```

and use some other thing than $to

Comment: I say this (that is could be a server problem) because I ran your script but using a private email address and I got the message

Comment: no..it doesnt help: I tried chaning email to gmail..which accepts emails easily..I still get this: Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\email.php on line 16

Comment: but are you sure that you should be able to send emails? do you have a smtp server installed?

Comment: also: you said that you made changes to your php.ini file. did you restart the apache server after that? only after a restart the changes will be used

Comment: what is smptp server, I have xamp and windows xp package 3.. If smtp didnt come with them..I dont think i have

Comment: I don't think that you have it by default.. but I am not sure.. maybe someone else can confirm/infirm this.. but you can test by changing the server used to another one.. you say that you have a gmail acccount.. you should be able to use gmail server with your email address as users and your email password for authentication.. if it works using external server then you don't have a mail server

Comment: damn..I prefer having smpt server installed on my pc. What if I upload the site..do they provide me with an email? or mail server..so it means I need to do the process twice...